# How do I log unique authors in git?

Tags: git

I have a big project with many authors.

For example,

```
user1 - commit1
user2 - commit2
user1 - commit3
```

I want to get all unique authors.
The result must be ***user1 user2***

How do I log unique authors in git?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here's one easy way:

```
git log --format="%an" | sort -u
```

Comment: Well, this is clearly superior :) I definitely need to take a look at log formats, thank you for the tip!

Comment: What does "|" symbol mean? I think it means "AND". Am I right?

Comment: @Voloda2 actually, no. It is a [shell pipe](http://www.dsj.net/compedge/shellbasics1.html), an outstandingly useful tool to combine console applications.

Answer (score 9):

Try out this one:

```
 git shortlog -s | awk '{print $2,$3}' | sort -fu
```

**Edit**: This will get you the emails as well

```
git shortlog -se | sed -re 's/^\s*[[:digit:]]*\s*//' | sort -fu
```

or, on macOS without the `-r` flag - *highlighted by Oliver in comments below* - would be:

`git shortlog -se | sed -e 's/^\s*[[:digit:]]*\s*//' | sort -fu`

Comment: on MacOS `-r` is not valid for `sed` (can be omitted)

Comment: How do you get the name and email but no number in front?

Comment: This answer works better for me than the accepted one b/c it does take into account the `.mailmap` file.

Comment: Seems like the same result can be archieved with this command too: `git log --format='%an <%ae>' | sort -fu`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to get the authors and committers so below is the https://devhints.io/git-log to helpful commands.

code below gets you the `author name (%an) and author email (%ae)` in this format

`personName - person@email.com`

```
git log --format="%an - %ae" | sort -u
git log --format="%cn - %ce" | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is `gitqlite "SELECT DISTINCT author_name FROM commits"` using [gitqlite](https://github.com/augmentable-dev/gitqlite), which is a tool for running ad-hoc SQL queries on git data.

(Full disclosure, I'm a creator/maintainer of the project)